# Is it possible to create a google apps script that manipulates a file in android phone?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, gmail, configuration-files

I am using JuiceSSH for making SSH connections to my RaspberryPi whenever I want. What I need to do is swap the IP address value into the JuiceSSH configuration file with the IP address that will be sent by RaspberryPi in case of IP address change. I am thinking about using a google apps script in which I can get the new IP address value from the e-mail. But I don't know where the JuiceSSH app holds the configurations. And I do not also know whether I can manipulate any file into an android phone using a google apps script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script cannot directly access any files except those in your Google Drive.

You may be able to empower a script to indirectly change the JuiseSSH config - if you can...

1. Figure out where it is.
2. Set up a web server on your phone to accept incoming POST operations.

   - See this [LifeHacker blog](http://lifehacker.com/5920173/use-your-android-phone-as-a-full-fledged-web-server).
   - When a valid POST is received, decode the payload and use it to update the local file.
   - There will be security issues with this!
3. Write your Google Apps Script

   - Monitor your email for a message about a change in your Raspberry PI's IP address.
   - Figure out how to track the phone's IP address!
   - POST the update to your phone.
   - retry periodically until the POST is successful (since the phone's connection is not reliable)

Another approach would be to have a Google Apps Script WebService serve up the current address of the device; then a program on the phone could periodically reach out to the service to find out the address, and update the file.

Of course, if you connected to your Raspberry PI using a name instead of an IP address, you wouldn't have to worry about any of this.